# How do I install component designers in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

If I add `[DesignerAttribute("somenamespace.mycomponentdesigner, mydesignerlibrary.dll")]` to the top of a class and then install that class into the tool palette, how do I then get the mydesignerlibrary.dll installed into VS so that VS can find the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WinFormsCustomCtrl) describes the process you'd need to follow, but effectively you'd need to:

1. Copy the designer assembly into a folder and configure Visual Studio to search that path by creating a registry entry under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\<version>\AssemblyFoldersEx`, where `<version>` is the lowest framework version your designer assembly is compatible with.

   Note that your control projects target the earliest version of the Framework that your control will support. This is referred to as the minimum Framework version. A restart of Visual Studio is needed before the new search path can take effect.
2. Copy the runtime assembly into another folder; add your custom controls to Toolbox. This can be done either manually through “Choose Items…” dialog or programmatically with a Toolbox installation package.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using Toolbox in the Visual Studio.

In the toolbox window, click right button on the mouse and choose menu 'Choose Items', then you use 'Browse' button for adding your dll component, then you can see it in the toolbox window in the Advanced Section(in the bottom).

Comment: That's how you install the component itself, the designer (which is in another dll) cannot be installed in this fashion because it contains no installable components.